# Compilation error in foreach statement while looping an object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List' i

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach, signalr

In the Asp.Net Project MVC with SignalR, I am trying to iterate over a object returned by Service in the Javascript Client. I get the below compile error for the foreach statement present in the below code

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' because 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Can someone advise what changes should be done either in View/Service call ?

**View Code**

```
  @model  System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<JobCurrentStatusDetails>>

   <script type="text/javascript">


                var connection = $.hubConnection();
                var hub = connection.createHubProxy("JobDetailsHub");
                hub.on('updateData',function(jSonRefreshData){
                    console.log(jSonRefreshData);
                });
                hub.invoke('NotifyUpdates').done(function(jSonRefreshData){

                    @Model = jSonRefreshData
                    @{int countTiles = 0;}
                    @foreach(item in Model)
                    {
                        if(item.color == "red")
                        {}
                         if(item.color == "green")
                         {}
  }
                });
    </script>
```

Adding Server Side code

```
 public async Task<List<JobCurrentStatusDetails>> NotifyUpdates()
        {
       var hubContext = lobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobDetailsHub>    ();
       if (hubContext != null)
       {
           db =  DataAccess.DataAccessModels.GetDashboardCounts();

           return await hubContext.Clients.All.updateData(db);

       }
       else return null;
   }
```

The Controller code is below :

```
public  ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            var jobDetailService = new JobDetailsService(da);

            return View(jobDetailService.NotifyUpdates());


        }
```

Comment: Have you tried awaiting `jobDetailService.NotifyUpdates()`? e.g. `return View(await jobDetailService.NotifyUpdates());` This will require making your `Index()` method async though and will potentially bubble up even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a Task as the Model. You could do this instead:

```
public List<JobCurrentStatusDetails> NotifyUpdates()
{
   var hubContext = lobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<JobDetailsHub>();
   if (hubContext != null)
   {
       db =  DataAccess.DataAccessModels.GetDashboardCounts();

       return hubContext.Clients.All.updateData(db).Result;

   }
   else return null;
}
```

Comment: I also tried that earlier and I got this error message in run time:   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataAccessModels.Models.JobCurrentStatusDetails>'"}

Comment: @TheDamned Did you try with the .Result on the end of hubContext.Clients.All.updateData(db)? Either way you must be returning an object from updateData instead of a list.

Comment: Hi Pricey.. It worked now but failing in the View load. I debugged it and could see that data was being fetched in the Service and Controller objects. For some reason, jSonRefreshData is showing as null. Is my javascript code fine ? Thanks

Comment: @TheDamned From the code you've given I can see that you've passed jSonRefreshData in as a parameter to a function, but I can't see anywhere that you've initialised it.

Comment: @TheDamned Also, if I've answered your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!